# Visual Studio 2012 - PDF Manipulation

Tags: visual-studio, pdf

### Need to add a set of information to a pre existing PDF file on Visual Studio

Basically Where to begin ?

Situation Description:  I have a form from a company, I need to print data from a database to the PDF file programmatically. That's to say, my current system (a webservice) must generate a full formed PDF from pre-existing file with the data it recives from the client.

Why edit the PDF file ?

The PDF is  part of a set of documents from a survey, and must retain is original layout with no variations.

Comment: How are you going to know where to add the data? Do you have given coordinates? Or are there AcroForm fields to fill in? Anyway, you should look for and choose a general purpose PDF library. Then study the samples of that library, and if there still are specific issues, you may enhance your question.

Comment: The PDF is basically a form wich contains many fields. I took considerate time wondering about many ways to do it. I was able to convert the PDF into HTML, assuming that manipulating tags will be easy. I thought about taking on the Postscript, I'm considering using a Library as you suggested but there a lot of libraries. I really need a point where to start.

Comment: *The PDF is basically a form wich contains many fields.* - Are those *AcroForm fields*? Can you type into them using Adobe Reader? Or are they merely drawn form fields? *considering using a Library* - you first need to know what license is appropriate. Can you spend money for the library or not? Can you get along with a license like AGPL or not? ...

Comment: Are those AcroForm fields? - No they are simple drawn lines.
Can you spend money for the library or not? - I can't spend any money at this solution.
Can you get along with a license like AGPL or not? - I could make use of any software as long as the license, guarantees free use. AGPL seems right.

Comment: There may be images at certain pages in the document, and I would need to overlaytext  on them.  To that case, I'm considering removing the image and rendering the same image but from an HTML file, that has been generated in another application.
This application, makes use of a HTML Map to pin-point the places, and from user interaction, set the innerHtml of the elements ( <a> tag) to a correspondent value. In the end, we have an HTML map populated with text marks. That's why I see the HTML manipulation of a converted PDF as a good solution, but, that's my WebDesign head talking....

Comment: Overlaying text over existing content should not be a problem.

Comment: *I can't spend any money at this solution.* ... *AGPL seems right* - In that case you might want to look at iTextSharp. There may be other free libraries available for .Net, too, though.